# Split time period by hour

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am logging time periods in epoch millis. Like shown below:

```
start_time    | end_time      | duration
-----------------------------------------
1481460261912 | 1481460716464 | 454552
1481461049219 | 1481461291862 | 242643
....
```

This time is in UTC as it is stored as epoch. Now, I am able to convert this time to localtime for a day's period like this by 3 queries:

**1)**

```
SELECT sum(duration)  FROM duration_logs 
    WHERE date(datetime(start_time/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) = date('now') 
    AND date(datetime(end_time/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) = date('now')
```

**2)**

```
SELECT end_time-strftime('%s','now','start of day','utc')*1000 FROM duration_logs 
   WHERE date(datetime(start_time/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) != date('now') 
   AND date(datetime(end_time/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) = date('now')
```

**3)**  Opposite of 2nd for splitting start_time

By doing the sum of 3 duration I am able to get the duration of the day.

But, I need to split this by Hour for a given date. Specifically to plot on the graph and to show which was the busiest hour.

I am a little clueless how to do that. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

**EDIT:** The main problem here is to include durations when the time span is on multiple hours. For example, start_time is 12:30:00 and end_time is 13:30:00, then 12-13 time period should contain 30 minutes and 13-14 should contain 30 minutes.

Comment: To get rows for all hours, create another table with all 24 hours and join that with the log table.

Comment: @CL. , So, what I understood is I should log on both tables?

Comment: No; that other table contains exactly 24 rows.

Comment: @CL. A small example would be great.

Answer (score 0):

As, this may lead to a very very complicated query, I have choose to split with the code instead of in query.

However, if anyone is able to create that query, I would be happy to have a look.